# Display bootstrap modal after page refresh using ajax success and setTimeout

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to display a bootstrap modal after a page refresh on  the success function of a jQuery ajax request.  I think what's happening is that once the page refreshes, the setTimeout is wiped away so it never fires.  I need the page to refresh the content, but also want to provide the user with a dialog box that shows what occurred.

Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateVideoUrl", "ManageVideos")',
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function () {
                location.reload(true);
                $(window).scrollTop(0);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#SuccessModal").modal('show');
                }, 200);

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown + "." + "  Please see above if applicable");
            }
        });
```

If I set the timeout to 100 the modal starts to display and the page refreshes and I lose the modal.  Is there a way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than refreshing the page and then displaying the modal, I realized I needed to display the modal and when the modal is closed, fire the `location.reload(true)` and `.animate` commands:

```
//Put page to on refresh
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 100); //100ms for example
});

//Refresh page after modal dialog is closed
function ReloadPage() {
    location.reload(true);
}
```